# Call to undefined method PHPExcel::sheetCodeNameExists() PHPExcel

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel 1.8.0 library in Laravel 4.2. It was working fine till now but now suddenly I am getting this error.

> 'Call to undefined method PHPExcel::sheetCodeNameExists()' in /var/www/myfilerunner/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php

This is my code in Worksheet.php

> if ($this->getParent()) {

```
        if ($this->getParent()->sheetCodeNameExists($pValue)) {

            if (PHPExcel_Shared_String::CountCharacters($pValue) > 29) {
                $pValue = PHPExcel_Shared_String::Substring($pValue,0,29);
            }
            $i = 1;
            while ($this->getParent()->sheetCodeNameExists($pValue . '_' . $i)) {
                ++$i;
                if ($i == 10) {
                    if (PHPExcel_Shared_String::CountCharacters($pValue) > 28) {
                        $pValue = PHPExcel_Shared_String::Substring($pValue,0,28);
                    }
                } elseif ($i == 100) {
                    if (PHPExcel_Shared_String::CountCharacters($pValue) > 27) {
                        $pValue = PHPExcel_Shared_String::Substring($pValue,0,27);
                    }
                }
            }

            $pValue = $pValue . '_' . $i;// ok, we have a valid name
            >setTitle($altTitle,$updateFormulaCellReferences);
        }
    }
```

I have not changed any versions and this method exists in my PHPExcel.php. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons to get this error.

One of this is old version of **PHPExcel**. Please update the version.

[PHPExcel repository on GitHub](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Comment: Is it possible to update PHPExcel 1.8.0 version and get it solved or will I have to go for another library PhpSpreadsheet?

Comment: As per https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel, Old version is deprecated so you just have to download new one and `sheetCodeNameExists()` function is working fine.